# Rails form_for in function of another value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I'm trying to use the `form_for` helper in order to create a form that has a variable number of text fields.

on one page, I have a form that takes in two values :

`<%= form_for :specs, url: specs_path do |f| %>` 
`<p>
        <%= f.label :title %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>`
    `<p>
        <%= f.label :sections %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :sections %>
    </p>`

```
<p> 
    <%= f.submit %>
</p>`
```

`<% end %>`

This take me to another page where I would like to have a form that would have a variable number of text fields. The number of fields would be = to `<%= @specs.sections %>` 
I haven't added a regex yet ;) (I'll do it once I'm sure this is the best way)
if `<%= @specs.sections %>` is two, i'd want to have a form that looks like :
`<%= form_for :sections, url: sections_path do |f| %>`
    `<p>
        <%= f.label :head_chord %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :head_chord %>
    </p>`

```
<p>
    <%= f.label :section_1_chord %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :section_1_chord %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :section_2_chord %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :section_2_chord %>
</p>

<p> 
    <%= f.label :foot_chord %>
    <%= f.text_field :foot_chord%>
</p>

<p> 
    <%= f.label :camber %>
    <%= f.text_field :camber %>
</p>

<p> 
    <%= f.label :draft_position %>
    <%= f.text_field :draft_position %>
</p>

<p> 
    <%= f.submit %>
</p>
```

`<% end %>
</p>`

(section is the only variable aspect.)
I appreciate any suggestion! 
Thanks for reading :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a variable number of parameters to your server, you'd better put them in an array. This way your controller can handle them more easily. So instead of `section_1_chord`, `section_1_chord`, ..., go with `section_chord[]`. You can do that this way:

```
<%= form_for :sections, url: sections_path do |f| %>  <p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :head_chord %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :head_chord %>
</p>
<%= @specs.sections.each_with_index do |section, index| %>
    <p>
        <%= label_tag "section_chord-#{index}", "section #{index}"%><br>
        <%= text_field_tag 'section_chord[]', nil, id: "section-chord-#{index}" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

This way rails treats section_chord as an array. This code is untested an will most likely need some clean up, but it should work.

Comment: each_with_index is undefined. according to the local host.

Comment: and if I only want to use numbers as input value is there something different I should do? Thanks

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought sections is an active record array. If it is only a number, replace the loop with: `<% @specs.sections.times do |index| %>

Comment: To allow only numbers, change the text_field_tag to number_field_tag

Comment: Thanks, `<% @specs.sections.to_i.times do |index| %>` works for the record :) 
You were very helpful!

Comment: the only thing, is that the @specs.sections is printed in the page bellow that part of the form, do you know anything about that?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. Yes, to_i tries to parse strings to integers, I thought the `sections` was already a number.

Comment: Oh, if it is put outside of the form in the dom, then it is not working.

Comment: Im not sure what the problem is, but make sure you are closing the form after the loop.

Comment: It happens whether I close it right after, or if I continue it and then close.